# Find specific div within a loop and add class

Tags: jquery

Sure someone can answer this very quickly! I have some html markup which is a loop of similar divs, each div has a button which shows/hides a div within itself. I am struggling with the jQuery to locate the nearest "target div" to toggle the display class of it.

So, for each "companyItemWrapper" when the user clicks on the "execSummaryLink" button within it - it should toggle the class of the closest "companyItemWrapperOverlayWrapper" div

Example code is:

```
<div class="companyItemWrapper">
<h3>Company Name</h3>
<p><a href="#" title="Latest executive summary" class="execSummaryLink">Latest executive summary</a></p>

<!-- OVERLAY -->
<div class="companyItemWrapperOverlayWrapper">
<p>content...</p>
</div>
<!-- end of OVERLAY -->

</div>
<!-- end of COMPANY ITEM -->

<div class="companyItemWrapper">
<h3>Company Name</h3>
<p><a href="#" title="Latest executive summary" class="execSummaryLink">Latest executive summary</a></p>

<!-- OVERLAY -->
<div class="companyItemWrapperOverlayWrapper">
<p>content...</p>
</div>
<!-- end of OVERLAY -->

</div>
<!-- end of COMPANY ITEM -->

<div class="companyItemWrapper">
<h3>Company Name</h3>
<p><a href="#" title="Latest executive summary" class="execSummaryLink">Latest executive summary</a></p>

<!-- OVERLAY -->
<div class="companyItemWrapperOverlayWrapper">
<p>content...</p>
</div>
<!-- end of OVERLAY -->

</div>
<!-- end of COMPANY ITEM -->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this solution.

```js
$('.execSummaryLink').click(function() {
  $(this).parents(".companyItemWrapper").find(".companyItemWrapperOverlayWrapper").toggle()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="companyItemWrapper">
<h3>Company Name</h3>
<p><a href="#" title="Latest executive summary" class="execSummaryLink">Latest executive summary</a></p>

<!-- OVERLAY -->
<div class="companyItemWrapperOverlayWrapper">
<p>content...</p>
</div>
<!-- end of OVERLAY -->

</div>
<!-- end of COMPANY ITEM -->

<div class="companyItemWrapper">
<h3>Company Name</h3>
<p><a href="#" title="Latest executive summary" class="execSummaryLink">Latest executive summary</a></p>

<!-- OVERLAY -->
<div class="companyItemWrapperOverlayWrapper">
<p>content...</p>
</div>
<!-- end of OVERLAY -->

</div>
<!-- end of COMPANY ITEM -->

<div class="companyItemWrapper">
<h3>Company Name</h3>
<p><a href="#" title="Latest executive summary" class="execSummaryLink">Latest executive summary</a></p>

<!-- OVERLAY -->
<div class="companyItemWrapperOverlayWrapper">
<p>content...</p>
</div>
<!-- end of OVERLAY -->

</div>
<!-- end of COMPANY ITEM -->
```

Comment: @dubbs Happy to help

Answer (score 1):

```
$(". execSummaryLink").on("click",function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent(".companyItemWrapper").find(". companyItemWrapperOverlayWrapper").toggleClass("anotherClass");
});
```

That should do it.

Comment: event should be passed as function argument

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".execSummaryLink").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.companyItemWrapper').find('.companyItemWrapperOverlayWrapper').toggleClass('XXXX');
})
```